# Shark tool on iphone crashes

Tags: iphone, crash, shark

I am trying to use Shark to profile my app.  However, it crashes after I hit "stop" and it analyzes and then goes to "load session".  Only once when I decided not to select my app but chose to target "everything" did it actually display some trace.  However, I could not reproduce this case.  Does anyone have any idea what might be going wrong?  Could it be something to do with the wrong version of Shark or my SDK or some other detail?  I have the latest SDK and am running 3.1.3 on the phone.

The various documentation I've found on google or via Apple's docs don't seem to be terribly helpful, so if anyone has found some that's useful, I'd love to see it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may be sampling for too long (or at too high a sample rate) and running out of memory - try sampling for a shorter time and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried starting and stopping in just 1-2 seconds and when it's churning on the "Loading session" part, Shark dies.

As a sanity check, I build a debug version on the device, then I launch it separately (not through xcode), then I launch shark.  It takes a while (15-25 seconds) for shark to fill the fields for my device in the table and then when I go to start/stop, this crash occurs.

Comment: OK - doesn't sound good - the only other thing I can suggest is check on http://connect.apple.com to see if there is a newer version of Shark that you can try.